# Postgres selecting latest record from a huge table

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgres as the data storage for one my GPS based asset tracking project. The table which contains GPS data from thousands of devices is growing huge day by day. Now in many functions across the app (Web based admin panel, Customer Mobile App and etc.) I need to  select the last record for a specific gps device (based on device id). The table that stores the gps data has the device_id column, along with some other columns like lat, lng, speed, heading, timestamp etc.

When I use query like

```
select {columns}
from table
where device_id = xxx
order by record_time DESC
offset 0, limit 1
```

Here is the table schema

[image]

[image]

Note: Few columns are cut off from the screenshot.

It takes a long time for the query to get finished. I understand that this is a very common problem as the select query runs first, which selects all the data and then find out the top. I may lower down the initial numbers of row using where condition like "record_time within last 24 hours", but there is a catch. If a device is not sending data for more than 24 hours, it will select no record. I can increase the 24 hours to 72 hours or such to avoid this. But this is not full proof.

Another thought I had is to keep the last gps record in a separate table and update the record, every time I receive GPS data from a device.

My question is, is it possible to fetch the latest record from the table without limiting the record_time or having a separate table?

Comment: Have you tried using a window function? What indexes are in the table?

Comment: I believe a better approach to storing data in tables would involve database partitioning. It's a more effective solution.

Comment: Impossible to say why the query is slow without the ddl for the tables and indexes involved, and most importantly the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for this query. An index on device_id and record_time will most likely be the solution

Comment: @FrankHeikens It is a very common problem when we select the last record out of millions of records, as the select runs first and then the sorting happens. So I was looking for ideas / ways that are best suited for this use-case.

Comment: Next time, could you please share the information in plain text? What you need is most likely a single index on both device_id and record_time. The queryplan should confirm this

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's better to separate the GPS data into different tables. For example, there are three tables, the first one contains 24 hours records, the second one contains 24-72 hours records and the last one contains the records of history. You should make a mechanism to update the records into the proper tables. Maybe we could call it buff tables solution. If you do the query operation with less records table, it will spend less time. You can also create index for your table columns to improve the query performance.

Comment: Good idea, but the housekeeping required is too much of headache. If there is no other way than separating the data based on timestamp, then better I'll go for table partitioning.